# VS Code to debug a Java Maven project dependency from my Gradle project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, gradle, maven-2

I have the following structure:

```
    workspace 
     - blade
       pom.xml
       -blade-core
         pom.xml
         - target
           com.hellokaton.blade.2.1.3.jdk17.jar
           com.hellokaton.blade.2.1.3.jdk17-source.jar
     - proj2
       src/
       settings.gradle
       build.gradle
       etc.
```

i.e. blade has several sub-modules, I need to be able to trace into 1 of them, blade-core, during debugging proj2.

I have this in my settings.gradle

```
    include ':proj2','com.hellokaton:blade:2.1.3.jdk17'
    project('com.hellokaton:blade:2.1.3.jdk17').projectDir = new File("/home/david/dev/blade")
```

In my gradle.build I have:

```
    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'io.ebean'  version '13.6.5'
        id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '6.6.1'
        id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
        implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20220924'
        implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
        testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
        ...
        implementation 'com.hellokaton:blade:2.1.3.jdk17'
        implementation 'com.hellokaton:blade:2.1.3.jdk17-sources'
        ...
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
                srcDir 'build/generated_src/jooq/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            }
        }
    }
```

The ellipses are mine, removing lots of other dependencies so this example does take up too much space.

The blade jar and source jar are also stored in the local maven repository.

When I place breakpoint in blade-core src code it never gets hit. It just presents the interface from the .class file. I have tweaked this several ways but nothing has worked. Is it even possible to do this with VS Code? Do I need to switch to Eclipse be able to debug a Maven project from a gradle project?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the blade-core source code that is closer to the entry point of the code being executed. This will help narrow down whether the issue is with the source code not being loaded or with the breakpoint not being hit for some other reason.

Comment: The breakpoint is never hit, because the source code in the blade project is not attached to the proj2. If I try to step into the blade code I get the class file only. There does not seem to be a way of attaching the source code of blade. If blade were not managed (i.e. built with Maven) project I could probably get the settings.json `java.project.referencedLibraries`  `source` setting to work?

Comment: If you have the full error log and how to reproduce it, you can [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new) to get a developer response.

Comment: There is no error log. It simply does not work, no error.

To reiterate. I have a dependency on the blade project, which uses Maven for the build, for my proj2, which is built by gradle. There is a jar file with the source code in the `blade-core` blade sub-project `target` directory, `com.hellokaton.blade.2.1.3.jdk17-source.jar` I need to find a way for to link the debug of proj2 to that source jar, or to link it to the `blade-core` source code.